# Universal Binary rejected by App Store to upload

Tags: ios

I am using OpenX sdk in my project for showing Ads. But when uploading to App Store giving following error:

"We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Project Name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

The binary being analyzed must be an executable: /tmp/mz_2649519702156363842dir/Project Name.ipa/Payload/Project Name.app/OpenXMSDK.framework/OpenXMSDK

The binary being analyzed must be an executable: /tmp/mz_2649519702156363842dir/Project Name.ipa/Payload/Project Name.app/OpenXMSDK.framework/Versions/A/OpenXMSDK"

I need to upload Binary as soon as possible with this solution. Anyone the solution please help me.

Comment: So is OpenX a framework as in a dynamic library? (which is not allowed AFAIK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Open `Terminal` in your MAC. Follow these commands,

1. `cd <Path_to_directory>/OpenXMSDK.framework/`
2. `chmod +x OpenXMSDK`
3. `chmod +x Versions/A/OpenXMSDK`

This will make the required files as executable. Make sure you have added this modified framework in your XCode project.

Once you run these commands, the file should look like this in the Finder. Files will be converted to **Kind: Unix Executable File**.

[image]

Hope that helps!